# String replace function isnt responding

Tags: javascript, string, photoshop

I am writing a photoshop script in JS, at this point I ask the user to select and folder location and add all those files to an array. I wish to then parse the array so only the filename remains.

I get this error : ***fileList[i].replace is not a function***

I imagine its due to me passing in the wrong value or using the wrong type. Was hoping someone could explain the issue and help me resolve it please?

```
//Prompt for folder location
var Path = Folder.selectDialog("Select Folder Location for Renders")

// Use the path to the application and append the samples folder 
var samplesFolder = Folder(Path)

var fileList = samplesFolder.getFiles()

for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++)
{
    fileList[i] = fileList[i].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
} 

prompt("Complete")
```

Thanks for your time, AtB

S

Comment: What is `fileList[i]`?

Comment: Why are you using prompt?

Comment: putting a log-line in your code might help you. Add console.log(fileList[i]); and you will be able to see in the console which object you're trying to call the replace-method on.

Comment: It looks like filelist is an array of files and their direct path on the server. Either you are passing wrong parameter types or replace function is not supported.

Comment: Is /^.*[\\\/]/ surrounded by quotation marks?

Comment: Its photoshop script, I'm using prompt as my own Debug to halt the script, similar to a break point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occuring because you're expecting a string, and it isn't one.

http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js_html_3.0.3i/idcs5js/pc_Folder.html says that `getFiles`

> returns an array of File and Folder objects, or null if this object's referenced folder does not exist.

Fortunately, both `File` and `Folder` have these properties:

- fsName - The platform-specific full path name for the referenced file
- fullName - The full path name for the referenced file in URI notation.
- name - The file name portion of the absolute URI for the referenced file, without the path specification

Of course, if you don't want any of the path, and just want the filename, use `name`, otherwise, use the `replace` command on whichever suits you - `fsName` or `fullName`.

So - in your loop, you want:

```
fileList[i] = fileList[i].name
```

You may want to filter out the Folders in your end result.  That would entail something like this inside your loop:

```
if (fileList[i] instanceof Folder) {
    fileList.splice(i, 1);
    --i; // go back one i, because you just removed an index.  Note, if you're not careful, such shenanigans may mess up the second term of the for loop.
    continue;
}
```

One last suggestion:  I would personally find it cleaner to make a new array, rather than doing the replacement in position.  The language certainly supports what you're doing, but it still makes me twitch to go from `File or Folder array` to `string array`.  (Granted, you thought you were doing string array to string array.)  This would also simplify any issues with removing indices for folders, etc.

Comment: No problem.  The hardest part was finding documentation for this version of javascript.  Those calls are definitely not standard.